# How is Pandas Block Manager improving performance?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance

The Pandas documentation says :
*The primary benefit of the BlockManager is improved performance on certain operations (construction from a 2D array, binary operations, reductions across the columns), especially for wide DataFrames.*

I thought I understood how the BlockManager improves performance thanks to a great article (https://uwekorn.com/2020/05/24/the-one-pandas-internal.html), but I realized there was a small mistake in the example.

If I correct the mistake in the example :

```
a1 = np.arange(128 * 1024 * 10124)
a2 = np.arange(128 * 1024 * 1024)
a_both = np.empty((2, a1.shape[0]))
a_both[0, :] = a1
a_both[1, :] = a2
%timeit a1 + a2
%timeit np.sum(a_both, axis=0)

#Result :
895 ms ± 204 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.09 s ± 35.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It seems grouping data in a numpy array does not improve performance.

Is Pandas BlockManger still improving performance in 2022 ?
It would be great if someone could illustrate those "improved performance" with an example using numpy... (how grouping data or using a specific layout of data in memory could improve performance)

Comment: According to pandas (see explanation of the Block Manager) it's possible to improve performance by playing with the layout of data. However, I can't replicate those performance gains... Maybe someone with a good knowledge of pandas can ?

Comment: The BM groups columns with a common dtype into a common array.  The alternative is to treat each column as a Series, with its own 1d array data.

Comment: What I see on my machine is that there is no gain by changing the memory layout of numpy arrays. Having two separate 1d arrays is actually the same as having them      in a 2d array. What’s bugging me is: there’s something I’m missing since pandas claims to improve performance by grouping data in the same underlying array…

Comment: you are trying to simulate a 2 column frame, not a wide one.  `df=DataFrame(np.ones((10,10000)))` is wide and constructed from a 2d array.

Comment: I've just tried with 10 columns, and I have the same type of result...

Comment: You're right, actually for 30 columns "np.sum(a_wide, axis=0)" is faster than "a1 + a2 + ... + a30"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short : you need to work on more than 20 columns to benefit from the BlockManager for columns addition/multiplication.

There's actually a great explanation in Pandas documentation that I had missed :

*What is BlockManager and why does it exist?*

*The reason for this is not really a memory layout issue (NumPy users know about how contiguous memory access produces much better performance) so much as a reliance on NumPy's two-dimensional array operations for carrying out pandas's computations. So, to do anything row oriented on an all-numeric DataFrame, pandas would concatenate all of the columns together (using numpy.vstack or numpy.hstack) then use array broadcasting or methods like ndarray.sum (combined with np.isnan to mind missing data) to carry out certain operations.*

*Another motivation for the BlockManager was to be able to create DataFrame objects with zero copy from two-dimensional NumPy arrays.*

https://github.com/pydata/pandas-design/blob/master/source/internal-architecture.rst#what-is-blockmanager-and-why-does-it-exist